# CSS: Youtube-like video page layout

Tags: html, css, layout

In mobile version of youtube video page, the content goes as follows:

- Video
- Related Videos
- Comments

But in web browser desktop version, **Related Videos** turns into a **sidebar** right to both Video and Comments sections.

How did they do that? Their source code is way complex, and I can not figure it out. Could it be done somehow using css grid or `flexbox`?

So, the start point is:

**HTML**

```
<div id="video">Video</div>
<div id="related">Related Videos</div>
<div id="comments">Comments</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#video {}
#related {}
#comments {}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    #video {}
    #related {}
    #comments {}
}
```

Big thx

**EDIT**

I guess it is not safe, but it does what I need:

**CSS**

```
@media (max-width:768px) {
    #container * {display:block;}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="container">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Topic Title</h3>
            <p>Non-fixed height content</p>
        </td>
        <td rowspan="2">
            <h3>Related topics</h3>
            <p>Topic title 1</p>
            <p>Topic title 2</p>
            <p>Topic title 3</p>
            <p>Topic title 4</p>
            <p>Topic title 5</p>
            <p>Topic title 6</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <h3>Comments</h3>
            <p>Comment 1</p>
            <p>Comment 2</p>
            <p>Comment 3</p>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done using `flex` `order` and `float`

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="recommended">Recommended</div>
    <div class="video">Video</div>
    <div class="comments">Comments</div>
</div>

.content {}
    .recommended {float:right;}
    .video {}
    .comments {}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    .content {display:flex;flex-direction:column;}
        .recommended {order:2;}
        .video {order:1;}
        .comments {order:3;}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/09jnamna/

Answer (score -1):

You can use media queries.

Working [JSFiddle example here](https://jsfiddle.net/5odmk38u/1/)

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .video {
    width: 65%;
    float:left;
  }
  .sidebar, .related-video {
    width: 35%;
    float: left;
  }
  .comment {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
  }
}

/* Hide the related video in screens exceeding 768px */
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
   .related-video {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

I defined how the CSS should react when the screen is `MINIMUM` / at least 768px wide - which is;

- Show the video in 65% of the screen.
- The sidebar and related video in 35%.
- And the comments in 100%, which will be on the next "line", because the first 100% are already filled up.
- Hide related videos in screen larger than 768px wide.

You can [read up on media queries here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries_ex.asp)

Comment: I need related section be right to both video and comments https://i.imgur.com/2dghTlL.png